# Do I need to do anything after Bastion server"s global IP address changed?

Tags: scalardl

As far as I know, restarting the Bastion server created with Scalar Terraform will change the global IP address.
Do I  need to do anything with Scalar Terraform after Bastion's global IP address changed?
If I'm required to do something, can you tell me what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your question.

---

You need to do two things.

- First, update the `tfstate` file in network module.

  ```
  $ terraform refresh -var-file=example.tfvars
  ### Or
  $ terraform apply -var-file=example.tfvars
  ```
- Next, update the `ssh.cfg` file.

  ```
  $ terraform output ssh_config > ssh.cfg
  ```